# Не срабатывает отправка формы ajax после валидации

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Сама отправка формы работает, валидация работает. Но работает не так как нужно, а именно:

1. Ввожу неверное значение в поле
2. Срабатывает проверка
3. Ввожу корректное значение
4. Форма как бы отправляется, но данные в базе не обновляются.

Если все также проделываю, но уже не вызываю проверку поля - все добавляется.

**Примерный код формы:**

```
 <form id="myformvalidate" action="#">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Фамилия</label>
           <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" class="form-control custom-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Имя</label>
           <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control custom-control">
        </div>
    </form>
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <a href="#" id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update</a>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
```

**Код отправки формы:**

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    const id = $('#developer_id').val();
    const surname = $('#surname').val();
    const first_name = $('#first_name').val();

    $('#myformvalidate').validate({ 
        rules: {
            surname: {
                required: true,
            },
            first_name: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            surname: {
                required: 'Это поле обязательноe для заполнения!',
            },
            first_name: {
                required: 'Это поле обязательноe для заполнения!',
            },

        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../updateprofile.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    surname: surname,
                    first_name: first_name,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#' + id).children('li[data-target=surname]').text(surname);
                    $('#' + id).children('li[data-target=first_name]').text(first_name);
                    $("#fname").html(response);
                    $('#modalgenrealinfo').modal('toggle');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
        $('#myformvalidate').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже что валидатор сохраняет первоначальное значение, что было передано в переменных. Попробуй считывать каждый раз

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../updateprofile.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                surname: $('#surname').val(),
                first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#' + id).children('li[data-target=surname]').text(surname);
                $('#' + id).children('li[data-target=first_name]').text(first_name);
                $("#fname").html(response);
                $('#modalgenrealinfo').modal('toggle');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

И тогда ты можешь не выполнять .valdate метод при каждом клике, а вынести его конфигурацию в загрузку приложения

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myformvalidate').validate({ 
        rules: {
            surname: {
                required: true,
            },
            first_name: {
                required: true,
            },
       },
    messages: {
        surname: {
            required: 'Это поле обязательноe для заполнения!',
        },
        first_name: {
            required: 'Это поле обязательноe для заполнения!',
        },

    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../updateprofile.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                surname: $('#surname').val(),
                first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
            },
            success: function (response) {
                const id = $('#developer_id').val();
                const surname = $('#surname').val();
                const first_name = $('#first_name').val();

                $('#' + id).children('li[data-target=surname]').text(surname);
                $('#' + id).children('li[data-target=first_name]').text(first_name);
                $("#fname").html(response);
                $('#modalgenrealinfo').modal('toggle');
                return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
})

$('#save').click(function () {
      $('#myformvalidate').submit();
   });
```

Comment: А вы случайно не волшебник? Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Строчка `return false;` в обработчике `success` - бессмысленна.

```
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../updateprofile.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                surname: surname,
                first_name: first_name,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#' + id).children('li[data-target=surname]').text(surname);
                $('#' + id).children('li[data-target=first_name]').text(first_name);
                $("#fname").html(response);
                $('#modalgenrealinfo').modal('toggle');
            }
        });
        return false; // !!!
    }
```

Comment: это я знаю, но ее отсутствие или присутствие проблему не решает. Она вообще бессмысленна, там где она должна находится все равно не работает.